# Is it possible to change the date format while exporting to CSV in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, export-csv, select-object

I have a PowerShell script I run on a regular basis. Part of the script creates csv files that I later use to import data into various software programs.

The data is in a variable $enrolledStudents and the type is a System.Array

I use the following to export part of the data:

```
$enrolledStudents | Select-Object @{Name="SFIRST";Expression={$_.FirstName}},`
@{Name="SLAST";Expression={$_.LastName}},`
        @{Name="SGRADE";Expression={[int]$_.GradeLevel}},`
        @{Name="SBIRTHDAY";Expression={$_.Birthdate }} |    
    Export-CSV C:\temp\Exported.csv -notype -Append
```

The Export looks like:
"SFIRST","SLAST","SGRADE","SBIRTHDAY"
"John","Doe","6","**2009-11-22**"

The software I upload the data to needs the date formatted as “11/22/2009” so it would look like:
"SFIRST","SLAST","SGRADE","SBIRTHDAY"
"John","Doe","6","**11/22/2009**"

Is there a way to do this in the Select-Object ?

Comment: If ```Birthdate``` is a proper ```DateTime``` object you can just do something like ```Expression={$_.Birthdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") }```. If it's string you'll need to do some cutting and shutting - e.g. ```Expression={ "{1}/{2}/{0}" -f $_.Birthdate.Split("-") }```

Comment: Birthdate is not a DateTime object, it originates from a SQL query, I believe it is a string. The second part is a solution that will work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing. Just apply a little object typing magic...

```
$enrolledStudents | Select-Object `
    @{Name="SFIRST";Expression={$_.FirstName}},`
    @{Name="SLAST";Expression={$_.LastName}},`
    @{Name="SGRADE";Expression={[int]$_.GradeLevel}},`
    @{Name="SBIRTHDAY";Expression={([datetime]$_.Birthdate).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}} |
Export-CSV C:\temp\Exported.csv -notype -Append
```

Edit: Corrected the date format syntax

Comment: I like this answer but {([datetime]$_.Birthdate).ToString('mm/dd/YYYY')} should be {([datetime]$_.Birthdate).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}}  I tried using the T0String and failed before I posted the question, I believe I needed [DateTime]  This also works

Comment: Ha, ha. Didn't check what my output said before posting. Of course you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

I now have two working solutions and wanted to add a note. Both give the same output.

```
# Thanks mclayton
$enrolledStudents | Select-Object @{Name="SFIRST";Expression={$_.FirstName}},`
    @{Name="SLAST";Expression={$_.LastName}},`
    @{Name="SGRADE";Expression={[int]$_.GradeLevel}},`
    @{Name="SBIRTHDAY";Expression={ "{1}/{2}/{0}" -f $_.Birthdate.split("-")}} |    
    Export-CSV C:\temp\test-Renaissance.csv -notype -Append
```

and

```
# Thanks Dennis
$enrolledStudents | Select-Object @{Name="SFIRST";Expression={$_.FirstName}},`
    @{Name="SLAST";Expression={$_.LastName}},`
    @{Name="SGRADE";Expression={[int]$_.GradeLevel}},`
    @{Name="SBIRTHDAY";Expression={([DateTime]$_.Birthdate).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}} |  
    Export-CSV C:\temp\test-Renaissance.csv -notype -Append
```

I will use the second because for me, it is easier to read.
In my case it is very Important to have the **[DateTime]**$__.Birthdate.  I found numerous examples using the .ToString but did not come across one that used the [datetime]$_